# Laravel - Cache results of relationship tables using Eloquent queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a simple relationship Post x Files in my app (one post has many files and one file is associated to only one post). To make things more agile, I store the posts on the cache whenever it is not changed so I don't need to query the database again. The problem that I noticed is that only the Posts are being stored in the cache and not the files (and I suppose the problem is because the way I query them). My code is:

```
class Post extends Model
{

public function files(){
    return $this->hasMany('Ibbr\File');
}

}
```

The function for obtaining the posts:

```
public static function pegaPostsBoard($nomeBoard)
{
    $chave = 'posts_board';
    if(Cache::has($chave))
        return Cache::get($chave);

    $posts = Post::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->where('board', $nomeBoard)->where('lead_id', null)->paginate(10);
    Cache::forever($chave, $posts); //I "forget" the cache whenever the post is changed
    return $posts;
}
```

I also tried adding `->join('files', 'posts.id', '=', 'files.post_id')` before adding it to the cache but it didn't work. How did I noticed that the files are not being cached? Well, I reset the database so it cleans all the rows and I noticed that If I F5 the page the posts are still there (because they are cached) but not their files. So my question is how do I query it in such a way that the files are also stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `with` to append relationship to query results

```
$posts = Post::with('files')
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->where('board', $nomeBoard)
    ->where('lead_id', null)
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: This is called eager loading relationships (for reference to the Laravel Docs)